# React Native allow self signed certificates using axios

Tags: javascript, ssl, react-native, https, axios

I'm trying to make an API call to a `https://` resource using Axios inside React Native.

I'm making the call as follows:

```
const instance = axios.create({
            httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            })
        });


        instance.get('https://foodspecials-api.local/api/v1/specials/2')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('WORKED');
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log('FAILED');
                console.log(e);
            });
```

This, however, results in an error message **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: https**

I've created a SSL certificate which is self-signed.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: error is related to `new https.Agent` line, please check your imports

Comment: @Vivek I'm aware of this. Where do I import https from?

Comment: Have you got an answer to this?

Comment: Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: I got this working today, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74087759/3732075

Answer (score 1):

https module is for nodejs (does not work with react-native)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).